# iOS - Keyboard suggestions bubble is wrongly hidden behind keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit

In our iOS App the suggestions bubbles get hidden behind the keyboard. How can I prevent that from happening?

[image]

Comment: Is this a built-in keyboard with standard iOS autocorrect?

Comment: This is most commonly a bug. Try to fix it by restarting your Simulator (if it's Simulator) or reinstalling the app.

Comment: Yes, it's the standard iOS autocorrect and the bug persists after restarts / reinstalls and cleans. It also appears on my phone.

Comment: Two different places I've been at in the last year have had this same issue in their chat-style apps.   The current place SQA says it only happens on 6S and 6S+ and not on 6 and 6+ phones, but I have not yet confirmed that.  Still scratching my head over it.

Comment: Is this only happening with iPhone 6/6S/6+/6S+ phones and not with iPhone 5 sized phones?  Is perhaps your app running in iPhone 5 screen size on the 6-class phones?  (Ie, your main views are 568 high)?   When this happens to us, it only happens on 6-class phones where the physical screens are larger than the iPhone 5 size but the app is running in iPhone 5 screen emulation under iOS 9 (but not iOS 8).   Does not happen on actual iPhone 5 sized devices.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's the case. Thanks for the input, very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an Apple bug in iOS 9 for iPhone 6/6+ class phones running under iPhone 5 compatibility mode, i.e., there are no launch images or other indicators to iOS that the app supports the larger screens of the iPhone 6/6+ class of phones, so it runs the screen as if it were an iPhone 5 class phone, with main view 568 high.   The fix or workaround is to add native iPhone 6/6+ support to your app by adding in launch images for each of those phone sizes.  The problem will go away.  At least it has in my cases.